# No se crea archivo txt en C://

Tags: c#

Tengo un problema, realicé una aplicación de registros con servicios web y le agregué un Log para verificar los fallos en caso de que suceda algo extraño, como fallas de conexión.

Cuando instalo mi programa en otras computadoras y lo ejecuto no lo crea, alguien me puede ayudar? La computadora en la que lo instalo tiene permisos de administrador.

Esta es la sentencia que estoy utilizando:

```
System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Registro Leon-Comanja\\My Product Name\\logLeonComanja.txt", true);
```

---

Este tema ya quedó resuelto, bueno, concluido, porque la verdad nunca encontramos mis compañeros y yo la razón de por qué no creaba el archivo, realizamos todas las sugerencias aquí mencionadas pero ni así nos dejó, al final tuve que checar todo el código cada vez que ocurría algún error. Pero igual les agradezco que hayan comentado :)

Comment: ¿No será C:\ ?  Y una aplicación que no tiene derechos de administrador, nunca creará un archivo en la raíz del disco local, por lo que te recomiendo que cambies tu dirección.

Comment: Recuerda que debes usar [Variables de Entorno](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_de_entorno) para ello y no colocar la ruta de tu PC como tal.

Comment: que version de windows estas usando? porque por temas de seguridad puede que no tengas permisos para crear archivos sobre el raiz del disco. Deberias definir una ruta que sea en la carpeta dentro del perfil del usuario

Comment: Mi aplicación se ejecuta con permisos de administrador y ya cambié la ruta donde se almacena el archivo y nada.

Comment: podrias poner el codigo que usas para crear el archivo? por cual ruta lo cambiaste? cuando falla obtienes agun mensaje en la exception? que dice el mensajes

Comment: Esta es la sentencia que estoy usando

Comment: System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Registro Leon-Comanja\\My Product Name\\logLeonComanja.txt", true);

Comment: no se usa el @ con el \\, o es uno u el otro no ambos. Si usas el @ entonces la barra es una sola, sino usas el @ entonces si va con doble barra

Comment: En la máquina donde estoy codificando si lo guarda, teniendo las dobles diagonales y el arroba, el problema o lo que no entiendo, es por qué en otras máquinas donde lo instalo no los crea.

Comment: Te sugiero que edites tu pregunta, agregando un bloque más amplio de tu código para poder tener un contexto. ¿Cómo controlas los errores y qué tipo de excepción te genera?.

Comment: No estoy seguro que para guardar la ruta de un directorio donde estará tu registro de eventos, sea recomendable modificar las variables.

Comment: ok mas alla que local lo guarde, cuando lo ejecutas en la pc del usuario podrias mostar el mensaje del exception para ver el mensaje de error que se genera

Comment: Modificarlas? Las puedes utilizar en el mismo editor como una ruta para crear el archivo. En ningún momento he dicho que se debe modificar algo de la configuración.

Comment: Entendí mal entonces, gracias por aclarar ese punto.

Answer (score 1):

Es probable que haga falta agregar una arroba (`@`) antes de definir la ruta:

```cs
string[] lines = { "Primera linea", "Segunda linea", "Tercera linea" };
// el método WriteAllLines crea un archivo donde se escribe la coleccion de
// cadenas que definimos en el array 'lines', luego se cierra el archivo.
// No se necesita llamar al metodo Flush() o Close()
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\WriteLines.txt", lines);
```

Referencia: [*How to: Write to a Text File (C# Programming Guide)*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bh11f1k.aspx).

**Actualización Agosto 16**

El problema está en que usuarios normales no pueden generar archivos en `Program Files` y en otras ubicaciones en carpetas del sistema (`Program Files x86`).

Lo que podrías hacer es utilizar una carpeta en `Documentos`, de este modo se guardaría así:

```
C:\Users\<Usuario>\Documents\logLeonComanja.txt
```

Ahora, para obtener la ruta mencionada: necesitas importar `using System.IO;` y el siguiente código:

```
var pathToFile = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal),"logLeonComanja.txt");
```

Answer (score 1):

Cuando agregas una `@` delante de una cadena(`string`), los backslash `\` son interpretados literalmente, osea, asi y como estan escrito. Por lo que tienes que quitarle un `\` a cada par y veras como funciona. Si te fijas, nunca veras una ruta que tenga 2 backslash(`\\`) en windows a menos que sea de red y es solo al principio.

Por lo que seria así:

```
System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Registro Leon-Comanja\My Product Name\logLeonComanja.txt", true);
```

O sencillamente quitarle la arroba ya que poner 2 blackslash es lo mismo que utilizar @(en el caso de los backslash):

```
System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Registro Leon-Comanja\\My Product Name\\logLeonComanja.txt", true);
```

*Nota: verifica que la ruta exista*